# Micropython code to blink build-in Led of ESP8266 have no effect

Tags: iot, esp8266, micropython

I have uploaded micropython code that blink the build-in Led, everything passed perfectely and the file have been uploaded succssefully to the board, but when I unplug the board and plug it again to see the effect of the code uploaded nothing happened.

here is the code:

```
# main.py

import machine
import time

pin = machine.Pin(0, machine.Pin.OUT)

for i in range(10):
        pin.value(1)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        pin.value(0)
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

if I remember it correctly it should be gpio 2 instead of 0. Here is the [link to the docs](https://micropython-on-esp8266-workshop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics.html) where it is explained. So try this:

```
pin = machine.Pin(2, machine.Pin.OUT)
```

Just a sidenote: if you ask further question it is sometimes important which board you use e.g. wemos d1-mini which refers to esp8266-12e or the small esp8266-01. Just include it and you will raise the likelihood of getting a helpful answer.